# How to set fontweight?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, bitmap

I'm writing a simple application in c# .net core 6 and winform to "assemble" some pngs and write some text on it. [image]
This is the Photoshop output. The Title "Baldur the invincible" is wrote in Diablo Light when i'm writing it with DrawString with Font("Diablo", 30, FontStyle.Regular)

and this is my output with the Font.[image: My Output]

In photoshop i used Diablo Light font but in the list of system fonts, from C# code, i see just Diablo Regular.. and the result is different.
How i can set the fontweight ?

here some code:

```
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
        // All TEXT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
        {
            //string familyName;
            //string familyList = "";
            //FontFamily[] fontFamilies;
            //InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();
            //fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;

            Font title_font = new Font("Diablo", 30, FontStyle.Regular);
            Font sub_font = new Font("Diablo", 25, FontStyle.Regular);
            List<Font> list_fonts = new List<Font>();
            list_fonts.Add(title_font);
            list_fonts.Add(sub_font);

            RectangleF tit_rect = new RectangleF(165, 70, w - (165 * 2), h);
            //RectangleF sub_rect = new RectangleF(165, 82 + 30, w - (165 * 2), h);
            var v = m_dict_titles["Title"];
            string curr_string = tabbed_value[v].ToUpper();
            float offsety = WriteTitleTextf2(map_back, 0, TL(curr_string, false), tit_rect, list_fonts, StringAlignment.Near, 5);
        }
        
    public void WriteOnBitmapf(Bitmap bmp, int col, Font font, String text, RectangleF rectf, StringAlignment st_align, float stringi = 0.0f)
    {
        float size = font.Size;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

        StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
        {
            Alignment = st_align,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
        };

        Brush br = col == 0 ? new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)) : new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
        g.DrawString(text, font, br, rectf, format);
        g.Flush();
    }
```

[image: This is the output with FontStyle.Bold]

Comment: Would help if you showed us the font code you are using.

Comment: Sure, i'm editing the main post. WriteTitleTextF just call the WriteOnBitmapf below. As you see, photoshop show 2 types, 2 font weight, Light and Heavy.

Comment: `Font title_font = new Font("Diablo", 30, FontStyle.Bold);`  Also, dispose your `Graphics g` object by putting them in a using-block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i already tried it. Seem that is different. In photoshop the font have 2 weight, light and heavy. Bold in my code, produce very thick font. Last image show the output.

Comment: The Light and Heavy *weights* you see in PhotoShop are actually 2 different Fonts of the same Family. The `FontStyle` doesn't select a Font, just the way the currently selected Font is rendered. If the Font doesn't actually provide that style of representation, it's simulated (as with `FontStyle.Italic`, when the Font doesn't actually provide those glyphs) -- You probably have at least 3 Fonts (files) of that Family installed in your System

Comment: So i can't achieve the same result as the photoshop layout. I see around something about the FontWeight that seem to produce what i need. Maybe i need to write this application in WPF.. or maybe i can write it 8 time in all direction shifted by 0.2 0.5 pix.. :)

Comment: You can load Font files using the [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection), keeping in mind that the GDI+ graphic sub-system supports only True Type Fonts. TTF Fonts that use OTF outlines are only supported through a `PrivateFontCollection` (you cannot assign that kind of Font using the Form Designer. The Font is *rejected* as *not compatible*)

Comment: I think that i'll use the same trick to draw the outline to make thick the font. It's just a personal application. Thanks again for the infos.